# Execute multiple inner functions

Tags: python, etl

I'm currently working on an ETL process where I have all the separate functions working, however, I'm still having troubles to get it work in a main function.

```
def etl(url):

    def extract(url):
        return url_json_file
    extract()

    def transform(url_json_file):
        return json_transformed
    transform()

    def load(json_transformed):
        load_json_to_db
    load()
    
pass
```

This is the ETL schema. My objective is, that I pass the outter function `etl()` a URL string, and from that point the process goes like this:

- `extract()`: Takes in that URL string, scrape it and performs a `json.loads()` and returns it.
- `transform()`: Takes in the loaded json file, transforms it and returns a clean new dictionary with the data on that previous JSON.
- `load()`: Takes in the clean JSON dict. and loads it to X database

PROBLEM: I'm probably doing a wrong return action, even if I set those return values to `global`, the process DOES NOT END. It usually returns this error: `[WinError 6] The handle is invalid`

My question, therefore, is, how can I make an inner function take the returned value or operation from a previous function. I would appreciate any hint or tip.

Comment: `someVariable = extract()` ?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what a function *is*.  You are defining these functions to take a parameter - but are supplying no parameter when you call them.  The functions return a value, that is presumably useful - but you're not doing anything with it after the call.

Comment: You need to put the return value of the function to a variable. `json = extract(url)` then `transformed = transform(json)` etc.. Or, do `return load(transform(extract(url)))`

Comment: You'll save time by first following a basic python programming tutorial or exercise. Your example indicates you don't understand standard function definitions and I'm guessing you don't know what a class or method is either. Learn the basics of Python then try again, it will save you time in the long run and you'll gain new skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def etl(url):
    def extract(url):
        url_json_file = url   ## Do smt.
        print("first step")
        return url_json_file

    def transform(url_json_file):
        json_transformed = url_json_file ## Do smt.
        print("second step")
        return json_transformed

    def load(json_transformed):
        ###do some db insert operations
        print("third step")
        db_send = json_transformed
        return db_send
    return "ETL: " + load(transform(extract(url)))

print(etl(url="https://www.google.com"))
```

The result should be :

```
first step
second step
third step
ETL: https://www.google.com
```